# emit event send previous emitted data when app reconnects? swift

Tags: ios, swift

My server on socket.io with nodejs

when client reconnects emit event by itself send old emitted data,  is it possible?

```
socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
    print("emit socket connected")
        self.socket.emit("RoomAction", dict)
}    
socket.connect()
```